# What exactly does $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ mean in Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

> Exercise 2.18 (Wave propagators). Using the spatial Fourier transform, show that if $u\in C_{t,\mathrm{loc}}^2\mathcal{S}_x(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a field obeying the wave equation (2.9) with $c=1$, then
> $$\widehat{u(t)}(\xi)=\cos(t\lvert\xi\rvert)\widehat{u}_0(\xi)+\frac{\sin(t\lvert\xi\rvert)}{\lvert\xi\rvert}\widehat{u}_1(\xi)$$
> for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d$; one can also write this as
> $$u(t)=\cos(t\sqrt{-\Delta})u_0+\frac{\sin(t\sqrt{-\Delta})}{\sqrt{-\Delta}}u_1$$

What exactly does $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ mean in Fourier transform in this text?

Comment: From which text? You should tell us which book this comes from.

Comment: The operator which multiplies by $|\xi|$ on the Fourier side. Note that $-\Delta$ is the operator which multiplies by $|\xi|^2$ on the Fourier side, hence the notation.

Comment: @Ian can you spell this out in a little more detail?

Comment: Non-negative operators have square roots, $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ is the positive square root of the Laplacian.

Comment: It is the composition of three maps: take a Schwartz function, first take the Fourier transform, then multiply by $|\xi|$, then you take the inverse Fourier transform. You can certainly go beyond Schwartz functions but this is the basic starting point. The reason for this notation is that the Fourier transform of $-\Delta f$ is (up to some factors of $2\pi$) $|\xi|^2 \widehat{f}(\xi)$. So taking square root means you or multiply by $|\xi|$. Basically any algebraic operation you want to do with differential operators, you take Fourier transform, do algebraic operations then inverse transform.